# Regarding the floating point abi flag used while compiling an application for arm target

Tags: c, floating-point, arm, cross-compiling

I have recently written c applications for the arm target. In order to cross compile an application for the arm target, there was a flag `-mfloat-abi=hard` that had to be used. But I didn't actually understand what it means. Can someone please explain what the flag means. What changes will it make when compiling the application?

Answer (score 5):

The difference lies in the calling convention. ARM uses register-based calling conventions, in which both the arguments to a function (up to a limit, after which they start spilling to the stack), and the return value, are passed in registers (for the full gory details, see the [Procedure Call Standard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/index.html)). When it comes to floating-point values, the presence or not of a hardware FPU coprocessor raises a slight conundrum over how to deal with floating point values, giving two possibilities when generating code:

- **Hard-float**: you assume that floating point hardware *is* present, and FP arguments and return values are passed in FPU registers. It's more efficient when you *do* have an FPU, but is not portable to machines without one, where the code would blow up trying to access registers that don't exist.
- **Soft-float**: floating-point arguments are passed in general-purpose registers the same way 32-bit or 64-bit integers would be. The callee function can then transfer them into FPU registers to do its work if it has hardware support, or fall back to floating-point emulation if not. Thus your code can work anywhere with the right library support, at the cost of a slight overhead even on real FPU hardware (which may become more significant for trivial functions).

From that, you can probably deduce whay you can't mix the two - say you *could* compile a function call as soft-float, but link to a hard-float library implementing that function - your calling code might put a float argument in `r1`, but the callee code will look for it in `s0` and proceed to calculate nonsense with whatever garbage value was in there. Similarly, the library function would then return a float result in `s0`, but your code would run off with whatever happened to be left in `r0` and be even more wrong.

Thus if your toolchain provides hard-float libraries, you can only link to them if you compile your code as hard-float, and vice-versa. Note that the magic of multilib means a single toolchain might support both, via having both versions of every library and automatically picking the right one when you link.

Comment: Does Hard-float and soft-float depends on the system? From an windows OS I cross compiled a program for ARM using the -mfloat-abi=hard flag. So does that mean ARM uses hardware specific floating point instructions?

Comment: From your answer..my understanding is that if a system supports FPU hardware and if we want to compile the code for that partcular system then the -mfloat-abi=hard tag has to  be used. If its not used it doesnt load onto the system. Is it Correct?

Comment: If you're linking dynamically, then you need to match whichever ABI the target OS's libraries use (best to compile against the headers and libraries from the target device's filesystem instead of those packaged with the cross-toolchain, but at the very least make sure the latter use the same ABI as the former or you really will hit the mismatch at runtime). I'm guessing from this you have a hard-float OS on your device, but FPU support alone does not imply the ABI a particular OS uses (e.g. Android still uses the soft-float ABI on even though it supports VFP and NEON).

Comment: BTW, wherever _I_ say "soft-float" here I'm purely talking in terms of the calling convention - Rodrigo's answer goes into the actual implementation details at the library end (i.e. emulation vs. softfp, which is a decision a soft-float OS might make at dynamically runtime).

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html):

> `-mfloat-abi=name`
>   Specifies which floating-point ABI to use. Permissible values are: ‘soft’, ‘softfp’ and ‘hard’.
>   Specifying ‘soft’ causes GCC to generate output containing library calls for floating-point operations. ‘softfp’ allows the generation of code using hardware floating-point instructions, but still uses the soft-float calling conventions. ‘hard’ allows generation of floating-point instructions and uses FPU-specific calling conventions.

The default depends on the specific target configuration. Note that the hard-float and soft-float ABIs are not link-compatible; you must compile your entire program with the same ABI, and link with a compatible set of libraries.

That means that `hard` uses hardware specific floating point instructions. `soft` will **not** use those instructions, but it will implement the FP operations as a software library.

Finally, the `softfp` means that it will use the `soft` calling conventions (and other ABI), that is it will not use the FP hardware registers to passing or taking parameters, but it will use the hardware FP instructions, if available.

The `soft` and `softfp` are link-compatible, that is they use the same ABI, so you can mix them in the same program. But `hard` will use hardware registers for argument passing, so it cannot be mixed with the other two.

Which one to use? Well, that depends on the system you are using. OS libraries will be compiled for one ABI or the other, and the native compiler will just use that. But if you are using a cross-compiler, then you may need to specify the ABI manually.

The exception is that if you are using a OS with `soft` ABI, and you are running it in a hardware that you know is capable of hard-FP, then you can compile your programs as `softfp` and take advantage of that feature without breaking the linking.

Comment: Does Hard-float and soft-float depends on the system? From an windows OS I cross compiled a program for ARM using the -mfloat-abi=hard flag. So does that mean ARM uses hardware specific floating point instructions?

Comment: @Minions: That depends on what you call the system. What you should use depends on the CPU (some support hw-fp, some do not) and the system libraries. If you use `-mfloat-abi=hard` then it will use hw-fp where needed: if it works then it is probably fine.

Comment: I understood your point. But If a CPU supports hw-fp. Does it mean that no operation can be done without specifying the -mfloat-abi=hard flag? Why I am asking this question was..my application did not load on to the target and it was giving errors when I dint use the flag while cross compiling. I just wrote a simple program that did not use any floating point operations.

Comment: @Minions: _"Does it mean that no operation can be done without specifying the -mfloat-abi=hard flag?"_ Even if you don't use FP operations, you must use the same ABI than the rest of the system or your program will fail to link or fail to load. It is so to protect you, so that you will notice easily that you are using the wrong ABI.